# Domain access: users of subdomain1 should not see users of subdomain2

Tags: 6, domain-access

I would like to restrict users and content to a certain sub domain. I am currently using Domain Access module and it's going quite well. The only problem is that I cannot figure out how to configure it so that a user that is assigned to domain1 cannot see<sup>1</sup> users assigned to domain2.

Is this possible in Drupal 6, and how?

---

<sup>1</sup> By 'see' I mean that they should be aware of their existence. They should not see them when using a user reference field, not when going to the user's profile URL etc, etc.